# Ajax Error with redirection

Tags: javascript, ajax, rss, blogger

I want to ask about Ajax problem (javascript not jquery)...
I want to get URL from blog that contains RSS (XML format) I try to get the link https://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
With Ajax currently there are not any problems but sometimes I try to get the same link but with different blog name that supports FeedBurner so 
When I use browser no problems but with Ajax, It returns error because Of redirection from blogname.blogspot.com to feeds.feedburner.com/name

Code screenshot:
[image: xmlhttprequest]

Comment: ya i am fine. where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default feed URL will get redirected to FeedBurner if that is setup via settings. Using feed URL's which are unaffected by the Feedburner setup would be a better approach. The feed URLs that can be used -

```
<!-- Post HTML is not present -->
https://name.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary

<!-- Alternate URL for full feed -->
https://www.blogger.com/feeds/BLOGID/posts/default

<!-- in JSON format, the Feedburner redirect will be ignored -->
https://name.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json
```